# I want disable time (before now) in the dropdown when I choose current date in the text box using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery

*This is the thing that I am using, please check, if anyone could help me to perform this function with jquery*

*I have mentioned all the details below of HTML and the jquery function that I have tried*

*I have used calendar setup of jquery with the text box to pick the date and for a time I used dropdown, I want time before now disable when I choose the current date. *

`This is my date text box`

```
<input name="SetDueDate" type="text" id="SetDueDate" placeholder="Date" onchange="DisableTimeSlots()" style="width:44%;">
```

`This is my time dropdown`

```
<select name="SetTime" id="SetTime" style="width:44%;">
            <option value="1|1">09:00:00</option>
            <option value="2|1">09:15:00</option>
            <option value="3|1">09:30:00</option>
            <option value="4|1">09:45:00</option>
            <option value="5|1">10:00:00</option>
            <option value="6|1">10:15:00</option>
            <option value="7|1">10:30:00</option>
            <option value="8|1">10:45:00</option>
            <option value="9|1">11:00:00</option>
            <option value="10|1">11:15:00</option>
            <option value="11|1">11:30:00</option>
            <option value="12|1">11:45:00</option>
            <option value="13|1">12:00:00</option>
            <option value="14|1">12:15:00</option>
            <option value="15|1">12:30:00</option>
            <option value="16|1">12:45:00</option>
            <option value="17|1">13:00:00</option>
            <option value="18|1">13:15:00</option>
            <option value="19|1">13:30:00</option>
            <option value="20|1">13:45:00</option>
            <option value="21|1">14:00:00</option>
            <option value="22|1">14:15:00</option>
            <option value="23|1">14:30:00</option>
            <option value="24|1">14:45:00</option>
            <option value="25|1">15:00:00</option>
            <option value="26|1">15:15:00</option>
            <option value="27|1">15:30:00</option>
            <option value="28|1">15:45:00</option>
            <option value="29|1">16:00:00</option>
            <option value="30|1">16:15:00</option>
            <option value="31|1">16:30:00</option>
            <option value="32|1">16:45:00</option>
            <option value="33|1">17:00:00</option>
            <option value="34|1">17:15:00</option>
            <option value="35|1">17:30:00</option>
            <option value="36|1">17:45:00</option>
            <option value="37|1">18:00:00</option>
            <option value="38|1">18:15:00</option>
            <option value="39|1">18:30:00</option>
            <option value="40|1">18:45:00</option>
            <option value="41|1">19:00:00</option>
            <option value="42|1">19:15:00</option>
            <option value="43|1">19:30:00</option>
            <option value="44|1">19:45:00</option>
            <option value="45|1">20:00:00</option>
            <option value="46|1">20:15:00</option>
            <option value="47|1">20:30:00</option>
            <option value="48|1">20:45:00</option></select>
```

`This is the calendar I am using with the text box, My function is didn't even called, please suggest how to call this function and how to read the date from the date text box.`

```
$(function () {
                CalenderSetup('SetDueDate', 'ViewCalenderDate');
            });


            function CalenderSetup(InputTxtFieldID, InputButtonID) {
                //Please Call its Library on its specific page
                Calendar.setup({
                    inputField: '' + InputTxtFieldID + '',      // id of the input 
                    ifFormat: "%m/%d/%Y",
                    //ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%d",          // format of the input field
                    showsTime: false,            // will display a time selector
                    button: '' + InputButtonID + '',   // trigger for the calendar 
                    singleClick: true,            // Single-click mode
                    dateStatusFunc: dateStatus
                });
            }
```

`I tried this function but not working`

```
function DisableTimeSlots() {
           var today = new Date();
           if ($("#SetDueDate").text() = today) {
               var CurrentTime = new Date($.now());
               var a = $("#SetTime").get(0);
               for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                   var splitvalue = a[i].value.split('|')[1];
                   if (a[i] < Now) {
                       a[i].hidden = true;
                   }
               }

           }
           }
```

Comment: First error in your code is `$("#SetDueDate").text() = today`. It should be `==`

Comment: I fixed this but still not working